# Magento Currency converter not working

Tags: magento, currency

I have installed magento with multiple currency converter in simple servers c-panel. But the currency is not changing in Frontend. I have found a following error in system log file. Because of that currency is changing only when clicking the next page. I think this is because of cookie problem

```
Warning: is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(var/cookie) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/hostname:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp)  in /home/hostname/public_html/magento/downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php on line 157
```

What was the issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure var folder has 777 Write permission. Hope you have already configured currency set up from **`Admin > system > Manage Currencies`**.
Thanks.

Comment: I have configured currency and var folder has 777 write permission

Comment: Not Working. What is the issue found in system.log

Answer (score 0):

Modify the open_basedir settings in your PHP configuration (See Runtime Configuration).

The open_basedir setting is primarily used to prevent PHP scripts for a particular user from accessing files in another user's account. So usually, any files in your own account should be readable by your own scripts.

Example settings via .htaccess if PHP runs as Apache module on a Linux system:

```
<DirectoryMatch "/home/sites/site81/">
    php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/sites/site81/:/tmp/:/"
</DirectoryMatch>
```